# Rbind to a vector using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, rbind

I'm having a simple problem but i'm a little confused how to get around it.

Let's say I want to create a vector that looks like ID = [1 2]. I use a for loop to get to that vector but instead of creating a vector, I think R is just adding the outputs up.

Here is my code:

```
block = 2
j = 0 
ID = data.frame(NULL)

for (j in block){
j = j + 1
ID = rbind(ID, j)
}
```

What I want is

```
ID
[1 2]
```

What I get instead is:

```
ID 
x2
2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are only loopoing through a single element, so instead of 'block', it would b e `seq_len(block)`

```
for(i in seq_len(block)){ 
      j = j + 1
      ID = rbind(ID, j)
  }
ID
#   X1     
#1  1
#2  2
```

Comment: THANK YOU! God bless your soul